# How should I set the path of css, img, js files for Spring MVC?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

When I see the page source of a certain page through google chrome,
I found this line,

I'm trying to copy the page on my own to practice my html/css skills.
This is the structure of my Spring MVC project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO6OX.jpg)

I copied the entire code of the page, and paste it on my index.jsp.
Also, I copied all the content of application~.css file and paste it on a css file that I created. 
(clicked the application~.css file on page source of chrome, and it opend a page with a lot of lines, so I assumed it's the content of css file.)

but, 
    
I don't think this line gets to my css file.
how come?

Should I put the file in resources folder?
or WEB_INF?

```
href="/resources/assets/application-eaa92ddb7d6e189695e3eeadad502b4d.css"
```

I added  resources folder into the path, but still not working.

please help me out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add this tag on your spring config file:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/META-INF/RESOURCES/" />
```

use this tag in jsp :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<c:url value="{path of your file}"/>
```

like this examle:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/My_CSS.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

For reference go through this article: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/